# How to prove the existence of the electron?

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons

Since the charge and the mass of the electron is so small, and as far as I know most experiments are carried out on a large number of electrons, how can we know that all electrons are the same charge and mass? It is possible that there are a lot of types of electrons differing in charge and mass, and the results we get is just the average of different values.

Comment: Because many experiments are done with one electron, or have results (bending with a magnet, say) that show no variation.

Comment: If you're going to make an assertion like this you should do some research to see what the evidence is and then refute it. There's nothing wrong with challenging established theories/models if you can **demonstrate** the shortcomings and offer a well-defended alternative. What you have here is pure speculation with no support.

Comment: In your body alone there are $10^{27} $ atoms, so any probability distribution function will predict a large number of low and high charge electrons at each end of the range of averages. I think you would notice that by now, although I do think it's basically a good(ish) question to ask, but bearing in mind the above  comments.

Answer (score 4):

Have you heard of Milikan's Oil Drop experiment? I think the results of that make it unlikely for there to be a range of charges on electrons. There is probably also experimental evidence that beams of electrons when deflected by a magnet are all deflected by about the same amount - the beams would spread out if the mass/charge ratios were different for different electrons.